# How to use npm Marked with HighlightJS

Tags: javascript, readme, javascript-marked, highlightjs

How do you use npm [Marked](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) with [HighlightJS](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js)? I'm trying to automate my docs to be parsed and styled. Looking at the following example from marked docs:

```
// Using async version of marked
marked(markdownString, function (err, content) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // console.log(content);
});

// Synchronous highlighting with highlight.js
marked.setOptions({
  highlight: function (code) {
    return require('highlight.js').highlightAuto(code).value;
  }
});

console.log(marked(markdownString));
```

I don't see how to use a `README.md` file instead of a string with manually escaped special characters. The usage examples don't involve any references to a `.md` document as input for the `markdownString`.

How can i pass the markdown string as a document (like form a file called `README.md`) instead of a manually escaped string and also have the final output include the styling?

The goal is to be able to pass in a linted (I'm using VS code `markdownlint`) README.md, the main document CSS and or highlightJS css and have the return value of the last line (`marked(markdownString)`) be something i can write directly to a `.html` file.

Another note if it matters: My markdown files also specify the the language in multi-line code blocks. For example a multi-line block of JSON in my README.md looks like this:

````
**BODY**:  

```JSON
{
  "username": "example@example.com",
  "p2setting": "4xx72"
}
```
````

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on [this](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/issues/578#issuecomment-56114330) post, the docs once specified the following but its been removed from the docs:

```
var fs     = require('fs');
var hljs   = require('highlight.js');
var marked = require('marked');

var markdownString = fs.readFileSync('./README.md');

marked.setOptions({
  highlight: function(code, lang) {
    return hljs.highlight(lang, code).value;
  }
});

var output = marked(markdownString);
```

Note you need to specify the encoding `fs.readFileSync('./README.md', "utf8")`.

A working example is:

```
const fs     = require('fs');
const hljs   = require('highlight.js');
const marked = require('marked');

const markdownString = fs.readFileSync('./README.md', "utf8");

const style1 = fs.readFileSync('./node_modules/highlight.js/styles/railscasts.css', "utf8");
// const style1 = fs.readFileSync('./node_modules/highlight.js/styles/solarized-dark.css', "utf8");

marked.setOptions({
  highlight: function(code) {
    return hljs.highlightAuto(code).value;
  }
});

const doc = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Marked</title>
  <style>${style1}</style>
  </head>
  <body>${marked(markdownString)}</body>
</html>  
`
fs.writeFileSync('./index.html',  doc);
```

Comment: when using code block, if no language is selected it throws an error `Error: Unknown language: ""`

Comment: For newer version of `highlight.js`, `return hljs.highlight(lang, code).value;` should be `return hljs.highlight(code,{ language: lang }).value;`